# Почему не удается выполнить команду push

Tags: git, github

сделал коммит последних изменений в проекте. в файле конфиг урл на удаленный репозиторий есть, даже когда ввожу git remote add origin  пишет, что такой репозиторий уже есть, но когда хочу запушить git push -u origin master выдает
repository  not found
линк рабочий сто пудов, вот для тесту https://worldwarmworm.github.io/lawfirm/
Почему гит так проитиворечит? пишет что репозиторий уже есть а когда хочу запушить - репозитория нет

```
$ git remote -v
origin worldwarmworm.github.io/lawfirm (fetch)
origin worldwarmworm.github.io/lawfirm (push)

$ git push
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

     git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Comment: Приложите вывод `git remote -v` и `git push`

Comment: Technology\Projects\lawfirm>git remote -v
origin  https://worldwarmworm.github.io/lawfirm (fetch)
origin  https://worldwarmworm.github.io/lawfirm (push)

c:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\work folder\Information Technology\Projects\lawfirm>git push
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master

Comment: В пост и с форматированием кодом

Comment: Впрочем, репозиторий должен быть вида github.com/username/reponame, а не на github.io

Comment: Видимо этот https://github.com/worldWarmWorm/worldWarmWorm.github.io.git

Comment: @Alexey Ten Не помогло. Не понимаю, на другом репозитории все то же самое делаю, те же команды, пушится нормально. 
В общем после замены названия репо на указанный тобой, ошибка:

> <code>To https://github.com/worldWarmWorm/worldWarmWorm.github.io.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/worldWarmWorm/worldWarmWorm.github.io.git'</code>
p.s.: сорри, что так неудобно читать, не получается отформатировать ни как код ни как цитату. как ты форматируешь?

Comment: Редактируй пост

Comment: Эта проблема и её решение описаны в каждом первом учебнике по git

Comment: Эта проблема и ее решение описано в каждом первом сообщении об ошибке самого git'а